# zend frmawork 1 set variable value of view in plugin

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

controller file

```
 class AController extends Model_BaseController
    {
         public function getCityAction()
         {
              $this->view->city = 'Ada';
         }
    }
```

plugin file

```
class Plugin_ConvertObjectPublic extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
     public function postDispatch($request)
     {
          $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
          $view = $layout->getView();

          $view->newCity = strtoupper($view->city);
     }
}
```

newCity variable pass to NULL value ?
how can I change variable of view in plugin?
Thank you for your help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the view is already formed in the method `postDispatch()` plugin.

You can add this method in your `AController` controller.

Obviously, your `AController`  controller already extend another controller `Model_BaseController`.
So you can add this method in your controller `Model_BaseController` like this:

```
class Model_BaseController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    ...   
     public function postDispatch()
     {
          $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
          $view = $layout->getView();

          $view->city = strtoupper($view->city);
     }
}
```

If you do want some controllers, you can create an intermediate controller like this:

```
class BController extends Model_BaseController {

     public function postDispatch()
     {
          $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
          $view = $layout->getView();

          $view->city = strtoupper($view->city);
     }
}
```

And

```
class AController extends BController  
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. :) If you are satisfied, please, validate the answer.